how to resolve issues on Kaggle,This preview is truncated due to the large file size. Create a Notebook or download this file to see the full content
enter image description here
how to solve the question on kaggle:
This preview is truncated due to the large file size. Create a Notebook or download this file to see the full content.
I have been downloading file,but Icannot resolve it.my file is .txt，it can only show few rows,how to resolve it.
